# Lightning On Chain Wallet - How do I get my Bitcoin back out

Tags: lightning-network

I've setup a Lightning Network Node.  Funded the wallet.  Played with channels and sent a few payments back and forth with a mobile wallet.  I recorded all the pass phrases when I make the Lightning wallet on the Lightning node.  But it didn't seem the private key was exposed to me while I set things up.

I've closed the channels and all my Bitcoin is now back in my on chain LND wallet.   How do I extract the Bitcoin out and send to my normal Bitcoin wallet.

Right now I'm beginning to wonder if Bitcoin moved to lightning network has to stay in the lightning network.

Can anyone "validate" if that is the case?

Thank you for your time and knowledge!!

Answer (score 1):

> **I'm beginning to wonder if Bitcoin moved to lightning network has to stay in the lightning network.**

When you close the channel, the remaining committed Bitcoin amounts are returned in an on-chain transaction.

Comment: Thank you for you response.  Yes.  They are returned to your lightning on chain wallet.   But how do you transfer them to a non-lightning on chain wallet.   I did not see any keys for transfe.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

lightning-cli withdraw

https://lightning.readthedocs.io/lightning-withdraw.7.html

withdraws and sends wallet funds to specified bitcoin address.